# How to access the textbox value created inside php tag to the ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am unable to access the textbox value which i created inside the the php tag to the ajax call. When i am printing the textbox value in ajax call its 'undefined', so is there any way to accesss the textbox value. See the comment in the code at line 39.

```html
<html>
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>categoryId</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>Operations</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql_query = "select category_id,category from cart_category_descriptions limit 10;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql_query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<tr id='.$row["category_id"].'><td>'.$row["category_id"].'</td><td><input type=text name="cat" value='.$row["category"].'></td><td><button class="deletedata">Delete</button><button class="updatedata">Update</button></td></tr>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).on('click','.deletedata',function(){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // Get the clicked id for deletion
            alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:{delete_id:id},
                success:function(data){
                         window.location.reload();
                }
            })});
        $(document).on('click','.updatedata',function(){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');// Get the clicked id for deletion
            alert($("#cat").val());// cannot access, undefined
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'update.php',
                data:{update_id:id,
                      cat: $("#cat").val()},
                success:function(data){
                    alert("updated");
                }
            })});
        </script>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access input boc value by id this is issue because id not mentioned in input attribute.

```
$(document).on('click','.updatedata',function(){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');// Get the clicked id for deletion
            cat_val=$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="cat"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'update.php',
                data:{update_id:id,
                      cat: cat_val},
                success:function(data){
                    alert("updated");
                }
            })});
```

Answer (score 2):

alert($("#cat").val());// cannot access, undefined

At above line 39, you have tried to alert value using "cat" id but 'cat' is not defined in -
`<input type=text name="cat" value='.$row["category"].'>`

**Solution :**

Change line-
`<input type=text name="cat" value='.$row["category"].'>`
with -
`<input type=text id="cat" name="cat" value='.$row["category"].'>`

Note : try with by putting static value of input field, like -
`<input type=text id="cat" name="cat" value='test'>`

**Full code with Solution :**

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>categoryId</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>Operations</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
                
                echo '<tr id="test cat id"><td>Test Cat Id </td><td><input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" value="test"></td><td><button class="updatedata">Update</button></td></tr>';
       
        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).on('click','.deletedata',function(){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // Get the clicked id for deletion
            alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:{delete_id:id},
                success:function(data){
                         window.location.reload();
                }
            })});
        $(document).on('click','.updatedata',function(){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');// Get the clicked id for deletion
            alert($("#cat").val());// cannot access, undefined
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'update.php',
                data:{update_id:id,
                      cat: $("#cat").val()},
                success:function(data){
                    alert("updated");
                }
            })});
        </script>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess, where is your `<head>`? Put your jquery in there. Also like the other answers you need to add to your input box `id="cat"` if you are using an `id`. From your code it looks like you are repeating this input box which makes using an `id` not something you want to do since an `id` value should only be used once. You should make it a class instead and add `class="cat"` to your input box and get the value as `$('.cat').val();` Since you are using `$(document).on('click','.updatedata',function(){` using this as a class makes more sense.

Comment: For the record, in most cases JavaScript is best located just before the </body> tag and not within the head.

Comment: @Cesar can you write the code to access the id of the closest "tr" tag using class="cat"